# SplitView Controller portrait mode- Top button keeps shifting to right

Tags: iphone, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I am using SplitViewController in ipad. On a button click from detail view, I open a modalview which is in full screen mode. Whenever I dismiss the modal view, the button which displays the table view in portrait mode shifts to the right.

If I continue the process of opening the modal view and dismissing it, it keeps moving to the right until it disappears to the right of the screen.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: BTW. This is happening on simulator. I am yet to test on the device.

Comment: This happens on the device too. Also the bar button which is used for portrait mode also appears on the landscape mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs when the any.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

I changed it to any.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet; and now everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

i confirm that changin modalPresentationStyle to UIModalPresentationPageSheet does the trick
for example:

```
MY_VC *controller = [[MY_VC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MY_VC" bundle:nil];
[controller setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPageSheet];
[splitViewController presentModalViewController:controller animated:NO];
```